# EXCEL: Using cell reference to make up part of a url path to another work book?

Tags: excel, url, path, cell

I am trying to get some information from a cell in another workbook, I am looking up the information by typing in this formula and pointing it to the path where the workbook is contained:

```
='Z:\Hewden Stuart Central Procurement Folder\Projects 2014\Supply Chain Compliance\X-Hire Supplier Audits Jul 2014\PLANT\AINSCOUGH CRANE HIRE LTD\[RiskMatrix.xls]Risk Matrix'!$AF$55
```

The information I want is contained in cell `AF55`.

This current formula works, however now I want to add two cell refereces into my url path, so say cell `D8` contains `PLANT` and cell `B8` contains `AINSCOUGH CRANE HIRE LTD`.

Essentially what I want to do is re-write the formula like this so that the cell references replace the text `PLANT & AINSCOUGH CRANE HIRE LTD`, however I get a `#REF!` error.

```
=INDIRECT("'['Z:\Hewden Stuart Central Procurement Folder\Projects 2014\Supply Chain Compliance\X-Hire Supplier Audits Jul 2014\"&D8&"\"&B8&"\RiskMatrix.xls']Risk Matrix'!$AF$56'")
```

Comment: Are you aware that INDIRECT does not work if the source workbook is closed?

Answer (score 0):

As stated **INDIRECT does not work if the source workbook is closed**

But there is a solution:

get Morefunc addon and use `=INDIRECT.EXT()` function, which works with closed workbooks.

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)